# NSString o String

Tags: swift

Bueno, se me vino una duda sobre los tipos primitivos de Swift, y algunas clases como NSString.

```
var miString : NSString
var miString2 : String

miString = "Hola"
miString2 = "Hola"

miString.length
miString2.characters.count
```

1.¿Porque y como es que los tipos primitivos tienen métodos?

2.¿Porque y como es que el objeto NSString puedo igualarlo a un String sin usar ningún constructor...(Como sería 
`NSString("String o lo que sea")`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24038629

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has de diferenciar entre [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring) y [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string). En Swift, un objeto de tipo `String` es un tipo primitivo, pero tiene [`extensions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) con métodos para poder manipularlos.

En el caso de `NSString` no es un tipo primitivo. Sólo tienes que mirar su [inicializador](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring#1666426) para saber que es una clase como cualquier otra que te permite utilizar cadenas y hacer operaciones con ellas.

Sobre el poder igualar un `NSString` a un `String` y al revés, simplemente es una implementación de los frameworks que permiten hacer esas operaciones.

Comment: Aaah claro, justo eso buscaba